# mysql restore problem with VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Im trying to restore my mysql db from the dumpfile i have created. This is my code:

```
Shell(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\mysql.exe" & " --user=root --database testdb < " & """" & txtRestore.Text & """")
```

But nothing is happening; data is not being restored in the db. Please help me in this!

Comment: Did you try System.Diagnostics.Process.Start method to call the mysql.exe ? Try running something like notepad to see if it works :)

Comment: Yes, same thing is happening in that method also! :(

Comment: Have you tried restoring without using VB .NET? I mean, manually using command line? If it works perfectly, I really don't see why calling the same method from VB .NET should fail unless there is some error in the syntax.